# Owncloud files:scan create function

Tags: owncloud

I'm looking to add a button on a external app developped for owncloud,

I would like to add a function to scan files for a user.

But i don't find any sources to make this ..

What should be the function to scan files without doing it in command lines with php occ files:scan ?

Best regards , thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Nextcloud instead of Owncloud but I never had the need for such a button. It happens all automatically on my side. Nextcloud has also the setting 'filesystem_check_changes' in config.php which enabled this autoscan. I suggest that you switch to Nextcloud and use this setting instead of a manual button.